# Cannot view code in Azure portal for function created / deployed via Visual Studio, yet I can when I make the function via the portal

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function that I created in the Azure portal. I added a timer function and some dummy code and it works fine; I created and wrote the code in browser - let's call this `FunctionA`.

I then created a new project (`FunctionB`) in Visual Studio 2017, added a new timer function and published it to the same Azure function mentioned before. Interestingly, when I go to the portal I can still `FunctionA`'s code, but for `FunctionB` all I see is the local.settings.json file - no code is visible.

I then get this message at the top:

> Your app is currently in read-only mode because you have published a
>   generated function.json. Changes made to function.json will not be
>   honored by the Functions runtime

I think this means the local.settings.json file in my VS2017 project has somehow made it readonly, but it doesn't explain why I can't even see the code in the Azure portal, let alone edit it.

Here is the code for FunctionB:

```
namespace DemoAzureFunction
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 5 * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}
```

The inbrowser code editing / viewing is a very cool feature. Even when I edit the default `local.settings.json` file and publish it makes no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's by design. Changing code does not make sense for VS created functions (precompiled functions) as your code already compiled to dll.

if you take a look on kudu (https://{your-function-app-name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole) you will see that folder stracture is different for portal and VS created functions.

More info about portal and VS created functions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp

Comment: Thanks for answering. My main concern was visibility of the source code, not necessarily editing it. I read online that setting the "Copy to Output Directory" was of the .cs file to "always copy" would cause it to be propagated to the portal but upon changing this setting in VS2017 I simply got an error.